# find grep exclude some file names for dos2unix

Tags: grep, find, dos2unix

so far I have gotten this far:

```
prompt$ find path/to/project -type f | grep -v '*.ori|*.pte|*.uh|*.mna' | xargs dos2unix 2> log.txt
```

However, the files with extensions .ori, .pte, .uh and .mna still show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to leave the excluding to `find`, see Birei's answer.

The problem with your `grep` pattern is that you have specified it as a shell glob. By default `grep` expects basic regular expressions (BRE) as its first argument. So if you replace your grep pattern with: `.*\.\(ori\|pte\|uh\|mna\)$` it should work. Or if you would rather use extended regular expressions (ERE), you can enable them with `-E`. Then you can express the same exclusion like this: `.*\.(ori|pte|uh|mna)$`.

Full command-line:

```
find . -type f | grep -vE '.*\.(ori|pte|uh|mna)$'
```

Comment: These didn't work, I wonder why. Does grep not do "filenames only" ?

Comment: @Sassinak: What command did you run exactly? All `grep` sees are the filenames listed by `find`, one per line if none of them contain newlines in them. So there is no "filenames only" dependence. By the way, you want to match the end of line, so the patterns should be anchored with `$`, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Okay, added the changes and it works perfectly. I prefer this one because it's "shorter", but the above answer worked as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
find path/to/project *.* -type f ! \( -name '*.ori' -o -name '*.pte' -o -name '*.uh' -o -name '*.mna' \) 
  | xargs dos2unix 2> log.txt
```